# C# FindElement - Pipe characters in Xpath

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Selenium C# does not find element

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(@".//*[@id='nnnn_record|OneToMany|SubGridAssociated|Mscrm.SubGrid.ndis_record.AddNewStandard']/span")).Click();
```

Tried `\\|` to escape but still not found

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(@".//*[@id='nnnn_record\\|OneToMany\\|SubGridAssociated\\|Mscrm.SubGrid.ndis_record.AddNewStandard']/span")).Click();

'\|' is not allowed in Visual Studio
```

Comment: There should be no need to escape the `|` character. Are you trying to find an element that has an `id` value of `nnnn_record|OneToMany|SubGridAssociated|Mscrm.SubGrid.ndis_record.AddNewStandard`?

Comment: Yes first driver line, however on execution is not found

Comment: I strongly suspect the reason it is not finding anything has nothing to do with the pipe characters. I might be wrong, of course, but it's up to you to provide the evidence by supplying a *reproducible example*.